# Problema com uso de listas em Java

Tags: java, lista

Tenho um arquivo carregado com 300.000 mil preços. Preciso colocar os preços em ordem crescente em uma lista. Se coloco em modo padrão, analisando de forma linear onde inserir cada preço, meu algoritmo fica muito lento. Alguém tem uma ideia de uma maneira rápida de fazer isso?

EDIT.:

São preços aleatórios que preciso ordenar.

19.5, 11.3, 17.43, 1.32, 36.45, etc...

Estou fazendo uma contextualização pois o que realmente quero fazer é diferente um pouco mas requer conhecimento do meu sistema. Isso é uma abstração.

EDIT. 2:

```
if (Type == 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < Objeto.size(); i++) {
                //Ordena pelo menor preço. Se o primeiro elemento tiver preço menor que algum da lista completa,
                //tal elemento é inserido anterior a esse algum
                if (PrimeiroElemento.getPrice() > Objeto.get(i).getPrice()) {
                    return i;
                }
                if (PrimeiroElemento.getPrice() == Objeto.get(i).getPrice()) {
                    //se os preços forem iguais, ordena pelo tempo
                    if (PrimeiroElemento.getTimestamp() < Objeto.get(i).getTimestamp()) {
                        return i;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Seria interessante adicionar uma pequena amostra de como estão estes preços no arquivo, editando a pergunta,

Comment: Feito. Preciso de basicamente um método de otimização.

Comment: Mas como eles estão dispostos no arquivo? Em uma unica linha assim, separado somente por virgula?

Comment: Eu já os peguei do arquivo e já mandei para uma Lista. Agora tenho uma lista desordenada com esses valores e preciso jogar para uma outra lista de forma que fiquem ordenados. Pensei em collections sort mas a cada vez que insiro um elemento, preciso da lista ordenada e pronta para ser usada. Isso cria a necessidade de ordenar a lista toda vez que insiro um dado, o que é inviável.

Comment: Exemplo: li da lista desordenada os valores 17, 18 e 11. Na lista ordenada, tenho que ter 11, 17 e 18 de forma que a qualquer momento que eu precisar usar essa lista ordenada. Ao mesmo tempo que vou ordenando pode ser que eu precise de utilizar os dados. Por isso, estou rodando a ordenação em uma thread.

Comment: Em vez de usar um `List` na hora de capturar os dados você pode usar o `Set` por exemplo `Set<Double> precos = new HashSet();`

Comment: O set por padrão já mantem os dados ordenados na sua inserção

Comment: Você pode postar o trecho de código que você preenche a lista?

Comment: Cara, isso é uma abstração. Tu não vai entender meu código muito bem pois é mais complexo, entretanto postarei em um edit na pergunta com uma parte compreensível.

Comment: A melhor e mais eficiente maneira é utilizar o `ConcurrentHashSet` ele é semelhante ao `Set` porém é próprio para trabalhar com multithreads. Indico você a utiliza-lo em vez do `List`, quando você da o `add` nele ele automaticamente já coloca o item na posição correta da lista: `Collection<Double> precos = new ConcurrentHashSet<>();`

Comment: Ai quando você for manipular você pode utilizar em `stream` com o `Java 8` desta maneira: `precos.stream()` você consegue realizar qualquer operação

Comment: Cara, darei uma olhada nesse CurrentHashSet. Obrigado.

Comment: descobri agora que o `ConcurrentHashSet` possui alguns problemas de ordenação, achei o `ConcurrentSkipListSet` que é mais estável, você pode criá-lo da seguinte maneira: `Collection<Double> precos = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<>(Collections.reverseOrder());`

Comment: vou postar um código como exemplo de uso

Answer (score 0):

Você pode trabalhar com o `ConcurrentSkipListSet`, ele trabalhar igual ao `Set` porém é apropriado a trabalhar em multithreads e também mais seguro com relação a ordem dos dados, segue um exemplo

```
// Define a ordem
Comparator sort = Collections.reverseOrder();
// Cria a collection
Collection<Double> precos = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<>(sort);

// Teste crio um pool com 100 threads onde cada thread adiciona dentro
// da lista um valor aleatório
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
for (int i = 0; i < 300000; i++) {
    pool.submit(() -> {
        precos.add(Math.random());
    });

}

// Finaliza o pool
pool.shutdown();
System.out.println("Done!");

// Exibe o top 10
int index = 1;
for (double p : precos) {
    System.out.println(p);
    if (index++ == 10) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Veja que ao final do processo a collection de preços tem todos os dados que as threads adicionaram de forma aleatória ordenados.

A ordem por padrão é crescente (Construtor vazio) mais você pode colocar de ordem decrescente ou personalizar seu `comparator` passando no construtor do `ConcurrentSkipListSet`, exemplo:

```
Comparator sort = new Comparator<Double>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Double o1, Double o2) {
        return Double.compare(o1, o2);
    }
};
```

Neste caso basta você adaptar o comparator para trabalhar conforme as especificacoes do `EDIT. 2:` de seu código